# No bean named 'DAOBean' available

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to fetch info form database and display it on wepage
i am using spring jdbc using annotation configuration it, it giving an error no bean named "DAOBean" availabe i checked it several times but couldn't solve it ,Help me

this is my AppController

```
 package shrikant.spring;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import shrikant.spring.DAO.AppDAOImpl;
    import shrikant.spring.model.Users;
    
    @Controller
    public class AppController {
    
        @RequestMapping("/")
        public ModelAndView homepage() {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
            List<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("AppConfig.class");
            AppDAOImpl DAO = context.getBean("DAOBean",AppDAOImpl.class);
            users = DAO.listUsers();
            modelAndView.addObject("users", users);
            context.close();
            return modelAndView;
        }
    }
```

this is my my AppConfig.java Configuration class using Annotation

```
package shrikant.spring.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import shrikant.spring.DAO.AppDAOImpl;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project1");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setUsername("shrikant@123");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="DAOBean")
    public AppDAOImpl AppDAO() {
        return new AppDAOImpl(getDataSource());
    }
}
```

this is AppDAOImpl.java

```
package shrikant.spring.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import shrikant.spring.model.Users;

public class AppDAOImpl implements AppDAO {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public AppDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> listUsers() {
        String SQL = "Select * from users";
        List<Users> listUsers = new ArrayList<Users>();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = `dataSource.getConnection`();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Users temp = new Users(rs.getInt("users_id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("email"));
                listUsers.add(temp);
            }
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            return listUsers;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is model class

```
package shrikant.spring.model;

public class Users {
    private int userId;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Users [userId=" + userId + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

    public Users(int userId, String name, String email) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

your code

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("AppConfig.class");
```

matchs

```
/**
     * Create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, scanning for components
     * in the given packages, registering bean definitions for those components,
     * and automatically refreshing the context.
     * @param basePackages the packages to scan for component classes
     */
    public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(String... basePackages){...
    }
```

which will try to scanning the "AppConfig.class" path but not register it ,so the context can not find your DAOBean.

you can try to use :

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("AppConfig.class");` you create a new application context, but it already there. you must use @Autowired annotation to inject bean into your controller.

Some tips:

- You can use @Service annotation on class AppDAOImpl to create bean
- Use interface when inject beans

AppDAOImpl

```
package shrikant.spring.DAO;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import shrikant.spring.model.Users;

@Service
public class AppDAOImpl implements AppDAO {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public AppDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> listUsers() {
        String SQL = "Select * from users";
        List<Users> listUsers = new ArrayList<Users>();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = `dataSource.getConnection`();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Users temp = new Users(rs.getInt("users_id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("email"));
                listUsers.add(temp);
            }
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            return listUsers;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppController

```
package shrikant.spring.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import shrikant.spring.DAO.AppDAOImpl;
import shrikant.spring.DAO.AppDAO;
import shrikant.spring.model.Users;

@Controller
public class AppController {
    
    private AppDao appDAOImpl;
    
    @Autowired
    public AppController(AppDao appDAOImpl) {
        this.appDAOImpl = appDAOImpl;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView homepage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        List<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
        users = appDaoImpl.listUsers();
        modelAndView.addObject("users", users);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

AppConfig

```
package shrikant.spring.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import shrikant.spring.DAO.AppDAOImpl;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project1");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setUsername("shrikant@123");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have gone through the code ,reason for it is App context is not able to register your component as bean.I have made changes and it is working .Datasource is getting created at app level all you have to is autowire it

@Component
public class AppDAOImpl implements AppDAO {
    

    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    public AppDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> listUsers() {
        String SQL = "Select * from users";
        List<Users> listUsers = new ArrayList<Users>();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Users temp = new Users(rs.getInt("users_id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("email"));
                listUsers.add(temp);
            }
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            return listUsers;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

   // @Bean
    @Bean(name="DAOBean")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project1");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setUsername("shrikant@123");
        return dataSource;
    }
    /*
     * @Bean(name="DAOBean") public AppDAOImpl AppDAO() { return new
     * AppDAOImpl(getDataSource()); }
     */
}

@Controller
public class AppController {
    @Autowired
    AppDAOImpl DAO;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView homepage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        List<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("AppConfig.class");
       // AppDAOImpl DAO = context.getBean("DAOBean",AppDAOImpl.class);
        users = DAO.listUsers();
        modelAndView.addObject("users", users);
        context.close();
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

or

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("shrikant.spring.config");
```

Comment: web page is loaded without error but now in console it is throwing " Access denied for user 'shrikant@123'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"